# Will there be serious performance degradation when using multiple threads to write to memory concurrently on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, memory

I wrote a multi-thread today. The task of the thread is to write data to a large array. A single thread takes about 0.7s, but it takes more than 20 seconds to write independently and concurrently with two threads. The same operation is under Windows or Multi-process seconds under Linux all are about 0.7s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define SIZE_IN_MB 256
#define NUM_BYTE (SIZE_IN_MB*1024*1024)
#define NUM_LONG (NUM_BYTE/sizeof(long))

#define CHILD_COUNT 2
#define STEP_SIZE   1  //use to avoid cache，when set to 8

unsigned long Time[CHILD_COUNT];

struct Arg {
    unsigned long *data;
    int index;
};

unsigned long diffTime(struct timeval *end, struct timeval *start) {
    return labs((end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec) * 1000 + (end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec) / 1000);
}

void getTime(struct timeval *t) {
    gettimeofday(t, NULL);
}

unsigned long writeData() {
    struct timeval start, end;
    getTime(&start);
    unsigned long *data = (unsigned long *) malloc(NUM_LONG * sizeof(long));
    for (int i = 0; i < STEP_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (size_t k = i; k < NUM_LONG; k+=STEP_SIZE)
            data[k] = 0x5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a + rand();
    }
    getTime(&end);
    free(data);
    return diffTime(&end, &start);
}

void *child(void *arg) {
    Time[((struct Arg *) arg)->index] = writeData();
}

void waitAll(pthread_t threads[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_COUNT; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
}

void printAverTime(int count) {
    unsigned long time = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        time += Time[i];
    }
    printf("Thread: %ld\n", time / count);
}

void thread_test() {
    pthread_t threads[CHILD_COUNT];
    struct Arg arg[CHILD_COUNT] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_COUNT; i++) {
        arg[i].index = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, child, (void *) &arg[i]);
    }
    waitAll(threads);
    printAverTime(CHILD_COUNT);
}

void process_test() {
    int p[CHILD_COUNT][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_COUNT; ++i) {
        pipe(p[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_COUNT; i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            unsigned long t = writeData();
            write(p[i][1], &t, sizeof(t));
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    unsigned long t = 0,tmp= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILD_COUNT; ++i) {
        read(p[i][0], &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
        t += tmp;
    }
    printf("Process: %ld\n", t / CHILD_COUNT);
}

int main() {
    thread_test();
    process_test();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The penalty you are paying when using multiple threads is not for writing to memory but for the fact that you are calling **rand()**, which involves locking, many times in the following nested loops in **writeData()**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < STEP_SIZE; ++i) {
    for (size_t k = i; k < NUM_LONG; k+=STEP_SIZE)
        data[k] = 0x5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a + rand();
}
```

So you are incurring a huge penalty because for each call to rand() only one thread can get in at a time and all the other threads have to wait and there is overhead to this waiting.

You can fix your code to avoid collisions in the inner loop by using a reentrant form of **rand()**, such as **rand_r()** (which is documented at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html)

```
unsigned int seed = rand();
for (int i = 0; i < STEP_SIZE; ++i) {
    for (size_t k = i; k < NUM_LONG; k+=STEP_SIZE)
        data[k] = 0x5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a + rand_r(&seed);
}
```